# Selfhosted server and SSL communication over TLS

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, self-host-webapi

I have an application that hosts WebAPI (HttpSelfHostServer) on windows service.
Communication over SSL (self-signed certificate for localhost).
Now I have two cases:

1. Windows7 - when calling API method (from the browser for example) I see that TLS 1.0 is used
2. Windows10 - the same call, but here we have TLS1.2

It is the same app in both cases. Moreover, I have set the following property in the entry point of the service

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

When I open any page on IE on Win7 I can see that TLS1.2 is ok.
What do I have to do, to force communication over TLS1.2 in my WebAPI on Win7?

Any ideas?

Comment: It is the caller who should use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to force TLS 1.2 connections. To enforce TLS 1.2 for your self hosting web service, you should modify server side TLS registry keys to disable old versions.

Comment: @LexLi - you were right. Modifying registry keys solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking to see if TLS 1.1 / 1.2 is enabled on your Windows 7 machine.

Example:  [1]: https://help.runbox.com/enabling-tls-1-2-on-windows-7/

You could also consider using IIS Crypto if you don't want to play in the registry:

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/

Use caution if you access these machines by a remote connection!